# IMAGE_INSTALL and IMAGE_INSTALL_append fails to add packages in yocto build

Tags: node.js, embedded-linux, yocto, influxdb

I am trying to build a Yocto Image for 
[PhyTec Mira Board with Freescale i.MX6](https://wiki.phytec.com/display/public/PRODUCTINFO/phyBOARD-Mira+i.MX6+Linux+Quickstart+PD15.2.0)
which should have `influxdb` and `node`, `npm` for an embedded application I wish to develop.

I followed the steps in the above mentioned Quick Start Guide and clone the respective repositories in a folder `sources` that was automatically generated via the script provided by PHYTEC.

The `sources` folder has all the other `meta-` layers for creating an yocto image. Within this folder I added the following `meta` layers:

1. [meta-influx by kraj](https://github.com/kraj/meta-influx) **Branch**: `kraj/develop`
2. [oe-meta-go](https://github.com/mem/oe-meta-go) and renamed the folder to `meta-go` **Branch**: master
3. [meta-nodejs](https://github.com/imyller/meta-nodejs) **Branch**: master

I added the respective `meta` folders in the `bblayers.conf`

#### bblayers.conf

```
OEROOT := "/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/poky"
BBLAYERS  ?= " \
  ${OEROOT}/meta \
  ${OEROOT}/meta-poky \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-phytec \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-yogurt \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-qt5 \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-ruby \
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/meta-go \
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/meta-nodejs \
  /opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/sources/meta-influx \
  "
```

### Initial Trial

I added the following in my `local.conf` file

```
# Install Packages
PREFERRED_VERSION_nodejs ?= "6.10.3"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nodejs = " openssl"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nano tmux ntp nodejs nodejs-npm packagegroup-core-buildessential"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " github.com-influxdata-influxdb"
```

and procedded to build the image

```
bitbake -k phytec-headless-image
```

The image was build successfully but when I boot the image on my board I cannot see a single package mentioned above to be installed. Not even `nano`, `tmux`, `nodejs`

#### Second trial

I rewrote the `local.conf` file with only `IMAGE_INSTALL +=` this time

```
# Install Packages
PREFERRED_VERSION_nodejs ?= "6.10.3"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nodejs = " openssl"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "nano tmux ntp nodejs nodejs-npm packagegroup-core-buildessential"
IMAGE_INSTALL += "github.com-influxdata-influxdb"
```

and ran the `bitbake -k phytec-headless-image` again but the there seemed to be no tasks that needed to be run as all the above mentioned steps were fulfilled in **Initial Trial**

What is wrong here? How can I actually see if `influxdb` is included in the package.

#### Previous trials

I followed the same steps for creating an image for Raspberry pi and I successfully created on wherein the on the Pi I typed `influxd`, `tmux` etc. and all such packages were installed correctly

Source for Nodejs:

[Nodejs on Yocto from EmbeddedArtists](https://www.embeddedartists.com/sites/default/files/support/com/iMX_Develop_with_Nodejs.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope already meta-nodejs is present in meta-openembedded change your `build/conf/bblayer.conf`

```
 ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-networking \
 ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-python \
 ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-multimedia \
 ${OEROOT}/../meta-openembedded/meta-node-js \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-go \
  ${OEROOT}/../meta-influx  \ "
```

Then clean and compile

```
bitbake -c cleansstate phytec-headless-image
bitbake -c clean phytec-headless-image
bitbake  phytec-headless-image
```

Comment: there is no `meta-nodejs` folder in the `meta-openembedded`. And do you think it should be `meta-nodejs` and not `meta-node-js`

Comment: from yocto 2.0 version (jethro) onwards meta-nodejs is present in meta-openembedded

Comment: Phytec usually use `krogoth`. But your solution worked. I think `OEROOT` is where the path got recognized while as the `/opt/PHYTEC_BSPs/../` complete path in the question wasn't